# How could i extract data that is being fetched to be displayed on html page

Tags: javascript, html, variables, scope, fetch-api

Im looking for a way to take the data that is being pulled from this api and perhaps add it to a variable which i can then have displayed on my html. Currently this is the api call:

```
fetch(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?${params}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.current));
```

This is an example of what the response object would look like:

```
{"request":{"type":"City","query":"New York, United States of America","language":"en","unit":"m"},"location":{"name":"New York","country":"United States of America","region":"New York","lat":"40.714","lon":"-74.006","timezone_id":"America\/New_York","localtime":"2022-05-25 15:18","localtime_epoch":1653491880,"utc_offset":"-4.0"},"current":{"observation_time":"07:18 PM","temperature":20,"weather_code":116,"weather_icons":["https:\/\/assets.weatherstack.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"],"weather_descriptions":["Partly cloudy"],"wind_speed":15,"wind_degree":170,"wind_dir":"S","pressure":1028,"precip":0,"humidity":43,"cloudcover":75,"feelslike":20,"uv_index":6,"visibility":16,"is_day":"yes"}}
```

I understand that i would eventually have to getElementById and set that innerHTML to the variable i store the data in, but I'm stuck in trying to store the data into a variable that i can use to display to the HTML page. Also i have an HTML page set up linking to the js file.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create/use the "listener/subscriber" pattern with the information you retrieve

Comment: I suggest you make a function which accepts the api response as a parameter and generates your html.  You can call it inside the second `.then`, instead of console.log.

Comment: Your code is already storing that data in a variable; you just need to figure out which parts you want to pluck out of it to display.  For example if you wanted to display the city from your given example data, it would be `data.current.request.location.name`.